# Change Particle attributes when inside a specific area

Tags: particles

Do you know a way to change some attributes of particles, when they enter a specific area (e.g. change color/material, make them slower)?!

I also want the particles that enter a specific area to stay inside it (e.g. don't fall through it's bottom face).

I am trying to let the particles fill out a specific mesh but don't know where to start.

This is how far I am:
[image]

The "0" and "1" are my particles (always facing the camera).
I want them to get slower and change their material inside the weird shaped Mesh (and the object should be invisible in the final render).

For now I just gave it a collision, I don't know where to start wwith this task. Thought about adding forces but ... meh...

Blend file:http://www.megafileupload.com/596c/particles01.blend

I want to change the color/material within Cycles renderer in the end.
But more important are alterations to the particle speed, so that you can guess the shape, if there are "enough particles inside the invisible object".

Comment: Please show your work so far as a screen image.  Are you willing to use either Blender Render or Cycles Render?  Are you already to committed to either?

Comment: Hi, I edited my post with an image and further information. Thanks :) In the end I don't mind using internal or cycles ...  I prefer Cycles though

Comment: You may want to separate movement questions  and color questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyed Particles is one approach

Note Blender Render, Cycles not considered

[image]

The green sphere holds the plan for particles moving from the yellow cube to the red tall box.
This is a starting point for further research.

You stated 
[I don't know where to start wwith this task]

Comment: I tried it this way. With a little fiddling I get close to what I need! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Particles in blender are very basic ..forces and keying attributes .. Is the only ways to control them . as far as I know.
So yeb use forces .